# Is showing that a subset of a vector space is spanned by a set of linearly independent vectors enough to conslude that the subset is a subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, independence

Sorry for any previous confusion. I think the title is asking what I want to ask now.

Essentially, the subset is described as having a specific form. If I show that any vector of that form is a linear combination of some vectors within that subset, is that subset a subspace?

I hope that was understandable!

Comment: The answer to your title is "no".

Comment: Just take a singleton, with just one non-zero vector. It is an independent set, but not a subspace.

Comment: What on earth? No, a linearly independent set *cannot* be a subspace, because it does not contain the zero vector.

Comment: Think of $\mathbb R$ as (real) a vector space, and take any non-zero number. This number is a linearly independent subset of $\mathbb R$, but is not a subspace of $\mathbb R$. Perhaps you are referring to the *span* of a linearly independent subset.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist But the span of whatever is a subspace.

Comment: @amsmath Yes, also true. I was only trying to make sense of what’s been said. :)

Comment: Ok. I have butchered what I was trying to ask. Give me a second to rephrase things... Sorry!

Comment: Regarding the latest edit, the answer is no. Let $v$ be any nonzero vector. Obviously $\{v\}$ is spanned by $\{v\}$, which is a linearly independent set of vectors, but $\{v\}$ is not a subspace.

Comment: Ok... After writing it out again, I think that I know the answer... You have a set of vectors of some form within a vector space. And you know that any of those vectors can be formed via linear combinations of certain vectors within that subset. Then you know that those vectors being linearly combined make a basis for the space of vectors of the given form. If you have a basis for the space, then the space is a vector space. And since it is a subset of a different vector space, it is a subspace. Does that make sense?